# why is Eclipse objecting to `static::$var`?

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I have the following static function in a PHP class:

```
static function __callStatic($method,$args){
    $called=NULL;
    if(empty(static::$collection)) static::slurp();
    if(method_exists(static::$objtype,$method)){
        foreach(static::$collection as $obj){
            $called[]= call_user_func_array(array($obj, $method), $args);
        }
    } else if (property_exists(static::$objtype,$method)){ //$method isn't a method, it's a property
        foreach(static::$collection as $obj){
            $called[]= $obj->$method;
        }
    } else if($method=='collection'){
        $called=static::$collection;
    } else {
        throw new ZException("$method does not exist");
    }
    return $called;
}
```

The static variables are all defined but possibly not set. The code appears to do what I want it to and throws no errors of any level.  But yet my new installation of Eclipse (Helios) PDT has marked every instance of `static::$var` as an 'unexpected static' error. If I replace `static::$var` with `self::$var` the Eclipse error goes away- but then the code doesn't work.

How do I convince Eclipse that these are not errors?

Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705
on 64 bit CentOS

Comment: Is it set to use php 5.3? Check Window > Preferences > PHP > Executables and Interpreter.

Comment: Eclipse sets the PHP Intepreter version to 5.1/5.2 by default IIRC.

Comment: @Gordon: I thought I had but it appears not to have stuck.  Working now.  Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: np. Adding the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Late Static Binding](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) was introduced with PHP 5.3. Check Window > Preferences > PHP > Executables and Interpreter to make sure Eclipse is using PHP 5.3.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the screenshot inclusion (actually, you had a +1 from me anyway, but I like it).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `static::` was introduced in PHP 5.3.

My guess would be that Eclipse is parsing according to PHP 5.2 rules. Either that, or its an oversight when they implemented the 5.3 rules in Eclipse.

Either way, you may be able to upgrade or patch Eclipse with a new rule set to get it to parse 5.3 syntax correctly.